# Installing mysqlnd for php 5.4.9 on CentOs 6.3

Tags: mysql, centos, rpm

Okay let me get straight to the point, I am a complete noob, and have never done stuff like this at all, I have read tutorial after tuorial but I cant get anything to work. When I tried to install the rpm file I got this error

```
rpm -Uvh ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/test/x86_64/php-mysqlnd-5.4.9-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm
Retrieving ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/test/x86_64/php-mysqlnd-5.4.9-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.ez4vvd: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 00f97f56: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.9-1.el6.remi is needed by php-mysqlnd-5.4.9-1.el6.remi.x86_64
```

so I tried installing that rpm file and got this error

```
rpm -ivh ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/rrpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/test/x86_64/php-pdo-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm
Retrieving ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/rrpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/test/x86_64/php-pdo-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm
curl: (9) Server denied you to change to the given directory
error: skipping ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/rrpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/test/x86_64/php-pdo-5.4.6-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm - transfer failed
```

I used the ftp links because I have no idea how else to get them to the server. I think I am getting overly frustrated with this, but I have to get this driver installed for any of my scripts to function correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: use a package manager -- `yum` on CentOS

Comment: You made a typo, that's why the second command didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the Remi repository to `yum` and install it that way. Yum will automatically deal with all the dependencies for you, so you don't have to follow the breadcrumb path all the way to the final dependency. Saves you lot of time and frustration :)

As root user, run these commands:

```
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
yum --enablerepo=remi-test install php-mysqlnd
```

The first command will retrieve the repository configuration file for Remi's repo. The second command will install the `php-mysqlnd` package and will also use the Remi repo to install it.

Comment: As soon as my server decides to come back online I will see if this works, me messing around knowing nothing about this is probably is what caused it to go down.

Comment: Messing around is the best way of learning things :) Let me know how it works out for you once you have it back on track.

Comment: unfortunately even a hard reboot isn't bringing it back online I fear I broke my server completely

Comment: Finally was able to try this out, but this is what it says `remi                                                     | 2.9 kB     00:00
remi/primary_db                                          | 451 kB     00:00
Setting up Install Process
No package php-mysqlnd available.
Error: Nothing to do
` which is the same thing I keep being told when I try to install anything... I am not sure what to do.

Comment: @kira423 I just looked at Remi's site and it appears the package your are looking for is actually in the `remi-test` repository. So try `yum --enablerepo=remi-test install php-mysqlnd` instead.

Comment: Gives me the same error :( this is why I always used a shared host, not very many of them had this support on their server, so I decided to get one of my own and I can't even get it to work lol

Comment: Strange, when I try this on my CentOS server it does find the package: `---> Package php-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:5.4.9-1.el6.remi will be installed`. Could you paste the entire command and it's output on a Pastebin so I can check the details?

Comment: I got it done, I am not sure what i did wrong but after I did it so many times it finally did it :)